# I cant seem to get the amount of decimals right using setprecision c++

Tags: c++, decimal, rounding, iomanip

I'm currently getting into subroutines/subprograms or whatever you call them in english and in this specific assignment that i'm trying to solve I have to calculate the average length of two words.

```
void Length(string const text_1,
            string const text_2,
            int & total_length,
            double & mean_length)
{
    total_length = text_1.length() + text_2.length();
    mean_length = static_cast<double>(total_length) / 2;
}

void Length_Program(int val)
{
    string text_1;
    string text_2;
    int total_length{};
    double mean_length{};

    cout << "Mata in två ord: ";
    cin >> text_1 >> text_2;
    cout << "Totallängd: ";
    Length(text_1, text_2, total_length, mean_length);
    cout << total_length << endl;
    cout << "Medellängd: " << fixed << setprecision(1) << mean_length;

}
```

I have set the precision to setprecision(1) and I assume it will only write one decimal but I keep getting two decimals.
my example is: abcd E
it should say that it is an average of 2.5 words but it says 2.51 for some reason. Can someone help me understand what i'm doing wrong?

Comment: Can you include your exact input and what you're seeing as output?

Comment: Yes I did at the end.

my input: abcd E
my output:  2.51

Comment: Works for me - live - https://godbolt.org/z/baq4dbsPY .  Please post a [mcve] with possibly a link to one of the online compilers.

Comment: I can't reproduce this. The output doesn't end with a newline character, perhaps the `1` is printed after the program has ended? Try adding `<< '\n'` after printing `mean_length`.

Comment: haha that actually did it, thank you so much. I will keep an eye out for endl from now on.

Comment: @Zeptuz -- `std::endl` does things that you hardly ever need. `'\n'` ends a line.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your problem is that you forgot `<< endl` on your last output line.  The return code shown by the OS is appended to your output.  The `setprecision` is working just fine.

Comment: Man I hate missing these small things, thank you so much!